# onDraw and ontouchEvent method

Tags: android

```
public class AI extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static Game gameAI = new Game();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        DrawGameAI view = new DrawGameAI(this);
        setContentView(view);
    }
}
class DrawGameAI extends View {

    public DrawGameAI(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        ....
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e){
            if(gameAI.getBlackTurn() == true) {
                gameAI.move((int) ((xPos - 7.0 / 1080.0 * width) / gridSize), (int) ((yPos - 7.0 / 1080.0 * width) / gridSize));
                invalidate();
                break;
            }

            else if(gameAI.getBlackTurn() == false){
                    gameAI.AI();
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

My idea is that I am the black and the AI is the white. Each time I click on on my board, it will paint a black piece on the position. Then I want my AI to automatically respond. (the gameAI.AI() will put a piece on the board when it is AI turn, gameAI.move() will switch the turn and put my black piece on the board)
My problem is that each time I have to click on the screen when it is the AI turn, which triggers the ontouchEvent to make it draw. 
I tried to change else if(gameAI.getBlackTurn() == false) to if(gameAI.getBlackTurn() == false), so in this way, after the first if statement, my turn is completed and the program will execute the second if statement, which looks like

```
if(gameAI.getBlackTurn() == true) {
    gameAI.move((int) ((xPos - 7.0 / 1080.0 * width) / gridSize), (int) 
    ((yPos - 7.0 / 1080.0 * width) / gridSize));

}

if(gameAI.getBlackTurn() == false){
    gameAI.AI();           
}
invalidate();
break;
```

This time, after each ontouchEvent, two pieces are on the board, then onDraw will be called and draw the my piece and AI piece at the same time. 
However, my AI is really slow. I have to wait for a while before the two pieces are drawn at the same time.
Therefore, what I want is after my turn, immediately paint the black piece on the board, then I do not have to touch the screen when it is the AI turn and after the AI moves, paint the AI piece on the board.

How can I do this? Thanks!